# GAN generates images only in yellow/green/blue, rather than original images

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I am experimenting with generating images using GANs from satellite images. Even though original images are imported with 3 colour channels, the images generated by the model in the first 300-500 epochs generally have a quite distinct colour scheme: yellow, green and blue. See examples below:
[image]
My expectations were the images would generally have similar colour schemes to the source images, even from the start of training. So my question is: is this normal behaviour and if not what could be causing it?

The code for importing the dataset is:

```
def create_training_data():
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), 1)
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (200, 200))
            training_data.append([new_array])
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

And the code for saving generated images is:

```
def save_imgs(epoch):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, 100))
    gen_imgs = generator.predict(noise)
    gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5 #rescaling
    img_array = np.reshape(gen_imgs, (1,200,200,3))
    plt.imshow(img_array[0,:,:,0])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig("generated/generated_%d.png" % epoch)
    plt.close()
```

I'm basing largely on this framework for [code examples.](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/125_126_GAN_training_mnist.py)

Could it be that in the first few hundred epochs the generator doesn't learn the colours? (I've only trained for 500 epochs so far, to start seeing results and understand what's behind the colour issue).

Or perhaps could it be that there is simply not enough training data? (I've started with a modest dataset of 200 images, again just to start experimenting.)

Any advice is appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be displaying just one channel. Maybe try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_array = tf.random.normal((1,200,200,3))
plt.imshow(img_array[0,:,:,:])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The colors are not generated by the GAN, it's just the viridis colormap, which is chosen as the default when you visualize greyscale images, which is what you do by slicing the 0th channel here: `plt.imshow(img_array[0,:,:,0])`. what happens if you do `plt.imshow(img_array[0,:,:,:])` instead?

More information about colormaps: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: Yes, that was it. My bad for not noticing this, thank you for your help!